# Problemas na Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, oracle11g

Estou com um problema com o resultado do método `SaveChanges()`.

Estou tentando salvar um registro, e ele é persistido no banco de dados, porém a aplicação está retornando a mensagem de `exception`:

> {"Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."}

**ApplicationService:**

```html
try
{
  using (TransactionScope transactionScope = Transactional.ExtractTransactional(this.TransactionalMaps))
  {
      if (distribuicaoAdmin.ID == 0)
      {
          this._DistribuicaoAdminService.Add(distribuicaoAdmin);
      }
      else
      {
          this._DistribuicaoAdminService.Update(distribuicaoAdmin);   
      }

      this.SaveChanges(transactionScope);
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  resultado = "Não foi possível inserir o registro.";
  this._SysLogService.Registrar(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
  return false;
}
```

Quando ele entra no método `this.SaveChages(transactionScope);` é onde ocorre o `exception`.

**Objeto**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma coisa que notei, depois que os dados são persistidos, meus objetos relacionados voltam com valor nulo. Meus outros objetos são:

1. Entidade;
2. despesaCobranca;
3. distribuicao;
4. tarifa;

Edit 1:

**Métodos SaveChanges:**

```html
public int SaveChanges(TransactionScope transactionScope)
{
    try
    {
        var changes = this._ServiceBase.SaveChanges();

        transactionScope.Complete();

        return changes;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

O erro dá no trecho `transactionScope.Complete();`.

Comment: o que está dentro do método SaveChanges ? no StackTrace da exception, verifica qual a linha que ocorre o problema

Comment: Fiz um edit na questão de onde vem o problema. Nesse método Complete(); eu não consigo mais avançar: "O símbolo não implementações."

Comment: é possível que `transactionScope` esteja nulo então. O problema vem de `Transactional.ExtractTransactional` mas não sei qual a implementação deste.

Comment: Consegui resolver com [Transactional] na implementação, porém agora não está salvando mais kkkk

Comment: agora não está dando o commit então hehe

Comment: pq vc ta usando esse escopo de transação?

Comment: Posta o que Transactional.ExtractTransactional(this.TransactionalMaps) faz por dentro pq como vc falou que ta com problema na transação, pode ser que o problema esteja aí

Answer (score 0):

Experimente fazer `transactionScope?.Complete();`. Dessa forma somente será feito o complete caso seja passado um transaction scope.

Também pode ser interessante colocar um transaction rollback no catch. Dessa forma, caso seja retornado alguma exceção, a transação seria revertida, evitando uma atualização parcial.